# Datetime picker in iphone

Tags: iphone, datetime, picker

I have one issue with Datetime Picker

In my firstview i have button.If i click that button it should open DateTime Picker in the second view.

After selecting the datetime it should show datetime in the firstview text field.

Please help in this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have wrote code but it is all explained VERY well [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/CoreDataBooks/index.html) by Wei-Meng Lee. Instead of showing a `UIAlertView`, pass the date to `yourTextField.text`

That's for a wonderful tutorial that will be helpful.

Further refrences: [Coredatabooks](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/CoreDataBooks/index.html) sample code from Apple.